# Kubuntu 20.04 network issue public networks

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 and I saw recently that I could not connect to networks which ask to first open the web browser in order to write the username and the password (which is often the case with public networks). It is working fine with a regular Ethernet connection or normal WLAN with password.

What would be the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the question about connecting to such networks (you are looking for "captive portal") without using the browser first or about not being able to connect when using a browser (and if so, which browser)?

Comment: I am using Firefox and I don't mind keeping using the browser for the connection. If there is also another easy method  without using the browser, I would also consider it but I don't necessarily need that.

Comment: The process is will described [here](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/firefox/detect_portal/) so you can check which part doesn't work. In particular, requesting the "success" file before the connection is done should fail.

Comment: It does not bring anything. Also, I have the same problem with Chromium. Maybe it has to do with DNS.

Comment: Hi again! I am still struggling with this issue. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: See [here](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/firefox/detect_portal/) and edit your question to 1) state exactly all the "captive"-related bits in your Firefox config and 2) using `wget` or `curl` with all verbosity enabled, what happens when you try to access th the success file.